# Does one need to clean old node.js sessions when stored in a database?

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, session, sql-delete

I have implemented a database session storage for my node application, but it seems like some abandoned sessions may stay in the database forever if a user never visits the application again or if he clears his cookies.

Is it necessary to perform a clean-up of expired sessions in my database from time to time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, in my opinion, keeping old session IDs is a bad practice. You should always clean them up to keep your database clean.

Concerning your question: As soon as a session expires, it is expired, thus, all information stored within that session will be lost. You should also make sure to keep the client session cookie in sync with the session, or make at least sure, that a session cookie expires not too long after the session itself expires.

This is btw not a node.js agnostic topic but affects other languages as well (e.g. Java. Here you can register an Eventlistener when a session expires and do clean up.)